# how to query data with data frequency every 10min

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle sql, Now I am wondering how to do every 10-30 minutes? Here is what I wrote for 10min based on the below example. Then I got below error

https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/group-rows-into-n-minute-intervals-with-sql

```
      end=end[:10]
      sql = f"""

            SELECT 
               WELL_NAME,
               TRUNC(OBV_TIME)+floor((TRUNC(OBV_TIME,'mi')-TRUNC(OBV_TIME))*1440/10)*10/1440 as "Date",
               DEPTH,
               AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"                
            FROM DATA.OFM_TEMPERATURE_V
            WHERE
               AREA_NAME = 'area'
               AND WELL_NAME = '{well}'
               AND OBV_TIME >= TO_DATE('{start}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  
               AND OBV_TIME <= TO_DATE('{end}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
               AND DEPTH>={dts_well_depth_min}

            GROUP BY WELL_NAME, RUNC(OBV_TIME)+floor((TRUNC(OBV_TIME,'mi')-TRUNC(OBV_TIME))*1440/10)*10/1440, DEPTH
                        """
```

```
GROUP BY WELL_NAME, TRUNC(OBV_TIME)+floor((TRUNC(OBV_TIME,'mi')-TRUNC(OBV_TIME))*1440/10)*10/1440, DEPTH
                        ': ('HY000', '[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00߫\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Comment: You're selecting `TEMPERATURE`, which is not in the list of expressions in GROUP BY. In the SELECT part, you should have columns or expressions that are either part of the GROUP BY as well, or are an aggegate function (like `AVG(TEMPERATURE)` or `MAX(TEMPERATURE)`. If you don't want to aggregate at all, you can omit the entire GROUP BY section.
The string of `\x00` at the end seems like a series of escaped null characters, which are not actually part of the message.

Comment: Yes Thank you GolezTrol, it worked now after adding AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"    . Thank you so much.